Oracle db query full scan vs index
I have an Oracle table that contains a lot of data that is separated into partitions by COLUMN1 (VARCHAR2).
This table also has COLUMN2 (DATE). There is an index (with same partitions as the main table) on COLUMN2.
I am trying to make a query that is ordering by COLUMN2 and fetching by subset of rows, but seeing full table scan.
select * from OUR_TABLE order by COLUMN2 fetch first 30 rows only;

Results in very bad performance, due to FTS.
Explain plan states: STORAGE FULL FIRST ROWS

select /*+ INDEX(OUR_TABLE IDX_COLUMN2) */ * from OUR_TABLE order by COLUMN2 fetch first 30 rows only;

Did not improve the performance
Explain plan still states: STORAGE FULL FIRST ROWS

select * from OUR_TABLE order by COLUMN1 fetch first 30 rows only;

When column by which partitions are created is used, the performance is fast and is using an index.
Explain plan states: BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID


Can COLUMN2 be null? That's one possible cause. You can check if that's the issue by adding where column2 is not null to see if it uses the index.

Drop the index and recreate it as global (remove the LOCAL keyword), and it'll work.
Explanation: a local index (one partitioned along with the table) is actually many discrete index segments (b-tree structures). While the data in them is ordered within each of those segments, there is no logical relationship between the data in one segment and that in another (unless the index leading column is also your partition key and you're using range partitioning). They simply cannot be expected to be in order over a partition boundary, so to enforce your order by Oracle would have to scan them in full and then performing a sort, which is far worse than simply scanning the table itself, so that's what it's doing.
